# How can I create files inside dynamically created directories?

Tags: c, linux

I need to copy files inside dynamically created directory. This is the code:

```
FILE *fp, *source, *target;
int i, j, k, counter;
char str[256], str1[256];
char ch;
const char *a[5];

a[1] = "submit.sh";
a[2] = "run.prm"; 
a[3] = "name.txt"; 
a[4] = "prot.pdb"; 

for (i=1; i<=4; i++)
{
    sprintf(str,"%s_%d",cur_folder, i);
    mkdir(str,"w"); 
    for (j=1;j<3;j++)
    {
        sprintf(str,"%s%s",cur_folder, a[j]);
        source = fopen(str, "r");
        if( source == NULL ) 
        {
            printf("Error in energies_step, can't open file source \n");
            return USERERR;
        }
        sprintf(str,"/home/salah/proteins/1L2Y/try5_4changes/_%d/%s",i,a[j]);
        target = fopen(str, "w");
        if( target == NULL ) 
        {
            fclose(source);
            printf("Error in energies_step, can't open file target %s \n",str);
            return USERERR;
        }
        while( ( ch = fgetc(source) ) != EOF )
            fputc(ch, target);
    }
}
```

This code breaks and tell me that `target` is `NULL`. Why can't I create new file inside the directory?

Comment: are (not) you missing a `main()` here?

Comment: If the directories don't exists you need to create them, it looks like you can do it better with python or something, unless this is embedded in some other code there is no reason to do it with c.

Comment: Please use 0-based array indexing.

Comment: what is `cur_folder`? I hope you know C uses 0 based indexing, right?

Comment: cur_folder is the same as /home/salah/proteins/1L2Y/try5_4changes/

Comment: Note `char ch;` should be `int ch;` for use with `fgetc` and `fputc`. Otherwise your program can't distinguish the file byte `0xFF` from `EOF` which is `-1`.

Comment: Did the compiler give you any warnings about the type of the 2nd argument to mkdir being incorrect? I think it should be something like `0755`, not `"w"`. Can you check the return value of the call to `mkdir` ?

Comment: YES, that fixed it.  Changing the "w" to "0755".  You rock Mark Plotnick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @MarkPlotnick in his comment, this line is not correct:

```
mkdir(str, "w");
```

But instead of writing explicit numbers for file permissions, as for example:

```
mkdir(str, 0755);
```

you should better use the corresponding symbolic constants, as for example:

```
mkdir(str, S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP | S_IXGRP | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);
```

The reason for better using the symbolic constants can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Permission-Bits.html#Permission-Bits):

> **Warning:** Writing explicit numbers for file permissions is bad practice. Not only is it not portable, it also requires everyone who reads your program to remember what the bits mean. To make your program clean use the symbolic names.

The symbolic constants are defined in the header file *sys/stat.h*.